# ASP.NET AJAX using UpdatePanels

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, jquery

Conceptually, my understanding of AJAX is requests sent to the server asynchronously aka in parallel. When I use multiple `UpdatePanels` on a page and trigger multiple async postbacks (say by using a button), I notice that the second request is not started till the first one is complete.

However when I use JQuery ajax and use `PageMethods`/`WebMethods`, my requests are processed in parallel.

Why is there a discrepency in the way ASP.NET AJAX behaves?

Also, when I click the button in the UpdatePanel repeatedly, it ***aborts*** previous requests. I was expecting them to be queued.

any help?

Comment: A request from UpdatePanel still runs through the entire page lifecycle. Hence, there is state data associated with each request. That's why two requests cannot run concurrently for the same session. Where as a Jquery ajax requests hit stateless static methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it must behave that way.

An UpdatePanel's asynchronous postback is still just that: a postback.  If multiple postbacks were allowed to occur in parallel, their new ViewStates would often be out of sync with each other.  Then, the very next postback would throw a ViewState validation error and/or one of the postbacks' modifications to the Page's state would be lost after the third postback completed.

On the other hand, page method and web service calls are not encumbered by the WebForms ViewState or page life cycle. So, as many of those may occur in parallel as the browser's simultaneous request limit allows (usually 4-8, but only 2 in some browsers like IE6).

Comment: +1 That's exactly what i was saying in my comment. ASP.NET AJAX model is a fundamentally broken design.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/08/08/Asp.net-Ajax-UpdatePanel-Simultaneous-Update---A-Remedy.aspx) seems like it addresses your problem and provides a solution. He uses some javascript to queue multiple requests and sends them to the server in a batch (I think).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It definitely addresses my question about requests getting aborted. Any thoughts on my question about the discrepancy in the ASP.NET AJAX behavior?