# Clicking another button before one’s action is complete

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have an asp.net web page that has two buttons. They reside in two different `update panels` and update two different textboxes.

I first clicked the First Button, waited for 5 sec and then clicked on the second button. What I expected as a result is that both the textboxes will have value – but only one has.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Why didn't the first textbox get updated? Is the first request getting aborted when I click the second button? Any msdn reference?
2. Is there any way we can get values in both textboxes even if we click the second button before the first complete?

**MARKUP**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AjaxTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyUI.AjaxTest"
EnableSessionState="False" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scrSubscribers" runat="server" />
<div>
    <div style="border-style: solid; border-color: #00FFFF">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="firstTextBox">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAssociateName" runat="server" Width="150px" MaxLength="81" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="firstTextBox">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDepartment" runat="server" Width="150px" MaxLength="81" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="searchValues" class="searchValuesDiv">
                <div id="searchLine1" class="searchLine">
                </div>
                <div id="searchLine5" class="searchLine">
                    <div class="btnSearchDiv">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnFirst" class="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="SearchSubscribersClick"
                            Text="FirstButton" ValidationGroup="Search" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstDate" runat="server" Width="150px" MaxLength="81" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="Div1" class="searchValuesDiv">
                <div id="Div3" class="searchLine">
                    <div class="btnSearchDiv">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSecond" class="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="SecondClick"
                            Text="SecondButton" ValidationGroup="Search" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSecondDate" runat="server" Width="150px" MaxLength="81" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSearchClickStatus" runat="server" Value="Blank Value" />
</div>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ExpandableSearchResultScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
    protected void SearchSubscribersClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        txtAssociateName.Text = "A_"+ DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    protected void SecondClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        txtDepartment.Text = "B_" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/4417442/284240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be derived from the question [ASP.NET AJAX using UpdatePanels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417442/asp-net-ajax-using-updatepanels)

@Sergey comment:

> A request from UpdatePanel still runs through the entire page lifecycle. Hence, there is state data associated with each request. That's why two requests cannot run concurrently for the same session. Where as a Jquery ajax requests hit stateless static methods.

@Dave Ward answer:

> An UpdatePanel's asynchronous postback is still just that: a postback. If multiple postbacks were allowed to occur in parallel, their new ViewStates would often be out of sync with each other. Then, the very next postback would throw a ViewState validation error and/or one of the postbacks' modifications to the Page's state would be lost after the third postback completed.
>
> On the other hand, page method and web service calls are not encumbered by the WebForms ViewState or page life cycle. So, as many of those may occur in parallel as the browser's simultaneous request limit allows (usually 4-8, but only 2 in some browsers like IE6).

Answer (score 1):

Any AJAX request is canceled, when new request is issued. This is not from MSDN. This is how AJAX requests work.

Comment: _"This is not from MSDN. This is how AJAX requests work"_ Even ASP.NET Ajax is on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398874(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That's true. I meant: This feature is not specific for technologies developed by Microsoft, so no need to search MSDN as this is standard Ajax behavior.